# Binding a window to a child collection of a parent window

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I have encountered a problem while using the MVVM model in WPF. Here are my objects:

**Views**

- MainWindow(View)
  (DataContext for this view binds to MainWindowViewModel)
- ItemViewWindow
  (DataContext for this binds an ItemListViewModel)

**View-Models**

- MainWindowViewModel
  (contains:
  ObservableCollection Items)
- ItemListViewModel
  (contains:
  ObservableCollection Items, 
  ItemViewModel SelectedItem, 
  Other properties/commands)

ItemViewWindow is accessed by a menu button on the MainWindow. I want to be able to pass just the collection from the MainWindow to the ItemView (note: I can't set it as the DataContext because it needs an ItemListViewModel). Then any changes made there should be reflected back in the MainWindow.

I know one way is to have the ItemListViewModel as a property of MainWindowViewModel instead of the Collection, then I can just pass that as the DataContext, but it seems wrong to have the extra functionality of the ItemListViewModel in the MainWindowViewModel. Is there a more elegant way of doing this without using the UI code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not either:

a: Make ItemListViewModel expose a property on which you assign the collection e.g.

```
class ItemListViewModel 
{
    public SomeCollectionType TheCollection { get; set; } // most likely you have INotifyPropertyChanged etc so probably more to it than get/set
}
```

Then just set it when you instantiate the ItemVM in the MainWindowViewModel

```
public void OpenItemList() 
{
    var itemList = new ItemListViewModel();
    itemList.TheCollection = CollectionFromThisVM;
    // etc
}
```

Or...

b: Use something like the `EventAggregator` pattern to publish a message containing the collection for the ItemListViewModel to subscribe to

The first method seems more straightforward

Comment: I had been doing something similar to (a), but didn't really like having to change data/context to something in the code-behind - I'll go with that for now. (b) is an option, but I want to try to avoid it if possible. I'll leave this open for a bit longer.